# Searching through a logfile with datetimes

Tags: perl, datetime

I am reading from a logfile and want the option to limit the search to a specific date range. The lines in the log file are in the following format `May 27 09:33:33`. I've already separated out the dates from the rest of the text in each line of the logfile. I just want to be able to write a statement like this

```
if(the date falls between June 10th and June 20th)
```

So just as an example I am trying to get the current time

```
use DateTime;

my $dt   = DateTime->now;
my $date = $dt->md;  
my $time = $dt->hms;
```

but wouldn't that put it in the format of mm-dd?

Comment: If you want to include messages between June 10th and June 20th, why are you using `DateTime->now`?

Comment: Its just an example. I may want to search for dates up to now

Comment: I wouldn't do it like this - you're better off parsing the date into a timestamp and comparing that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use timestamps / epochs for your comparisons.  Here is an example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl                                                                         

use DateTime::Format::Strptime;
use DateTime;

my $year = DateTime->now->year;

my $date_parser = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new(
    pattern => '%Y %B %d', # YYYY Month DD
);

my $start_date = 'June 10';
my $end_date   = 'June 20';
my $start_epoch = $date_parser->parse_datetime("$year $start_date")
                              ->epoch();
my $end_epoch   = $date_parser->parse_datetime("$year $end_date")
                              ->add( days => 1 )
                              ->epoch(); # Add one to get next day                                                                

my $parser = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new(
    pattern => '%Y %b %d %T', # YYYY Mon DD HH:MM:SS                                        
);

print "Start Epoch : $start_epoch [ $start_date ]\n";
print "End   Epoch : $end_epoch [ $end_date ]\n";

for my $log_date ('May 27 09:33:33',
                  'Jun 05 09:33:33',
                  'Jun 10 09:33:33',
                  'Jun 20 09:33:33',
                  'Jun 30 09:33:33',) {
    my $epoch = $parser->parse_datetime("$year $log_date")->epoch();
    print "Log   Epoch : $epoch [ $log_date ]\n";
    if ( $start_epoch <= $epoch and $epoch < $end_epoch) {
        # Less than end_epoch (midnight) to match previous day                              
        print "==> Log Epoch is in range\n";
    }
}
```

Outputs the following:

```
Start Epoch : 1433894400 [ June 10 ]
End   Epoch : 1434844800 [ June 20 ]
Log   Epoch : 1432719213 [ May 27 09:33:33 ]
Log   Epoch : 1433496813 [ Jun 05 09:33:33 ]
Log   Epoch : 1433928813 [ Jun 10 09:33:33 ]
==> Log Epoch is in range
Log   Epoch : 1434792813 [ Jun 20 09:33:33 ]
==> Log Epoch is in range
Log   Epoch : 1435656813 [ Jun 30 09:33:33 ]
```

Calculating epoch dates without using a core library is unwise, because now you would need to worry about days since the unix birth date (jan 1, 1970), leap days, leap seconds, and you would have so many edge cases trying to spoil your fun.  There are many ways of getting this wrong.  However there is an alternative:

If for some reason, you are opposed to using core library modules, you can search through a log file by converting the dates to a canonical form and then just selecting dates which fall into the range.

Here is the same example, but without using any modules, but using normalized (canonical) dates instead:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my %months = ( jan => 1, feb => 2,  mar => 3,  apr => 4,
               may => 5, jun => 6,  jul => 7,  aug => 8,
               sep => 9, oct => 10, nov => 11, dec => 12 );

my $year = 2015; # TODO: what year is it? Need to worry about Dec/Jan rollover

my @log_dates = (
    'May 27 09:33:33',
    'Jun 05 09:33:33',
    'Jun 10 09:33:33',
    'Jun 20 09:33:33',
    'Jun 30 09:33:33',
);

my $start_date = 'June 10';
my $end_date   = 'June 20';
my $start_canonical = canonical_date_for_mmmdd_hhmmss("$year $start_date 00:00:00");
my $end_canonical   = canonical_date_for_mmmdd_hhmmss("$year $end_date 23:59:59");

for my $log_date (@log_dates) {
    my $canonical_date = canonical_date_for_mmmdd_hhmmss("$year $log_date");
    print "Log Canonical Date : $canonical_date [ $log_date ]\n";
    if ($start_canonical <= $canonical_date and
        $canonical_date  <= $end_canonical) {
        print "===> Date in range\n";
    }
}

sub canonical_date_for_mmmdd_hhmmss {
    my ($datestr) = @_;
    my ($year, $mon, $day, $hr, $min, $sec) =
        $datestr =~ m|^(\d+)\s+(\w+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+):(\d+):(\d+)$|; # YYYY Month DD HH:MM:SS
    $year > 1900
        or die "Unable to handle year '$year'";
    my $month_first_three = lc( substr($mon,0,3) );
    my $month_num = $months{$month_first_three};
    defined $month_num
        or die "Unable to handle month '$mon'";
    (1 <= $day and $day <= 31)
        or die "Unable to handle day '$day'";
    (0 <= $hr and $hr <= 23)
        or die "Unable to handle hour '$hr'";
    (0 <= $min and $min <= 59)
        or die "Unable to handle minute '$min'";
    (0 <= $sec and $sec <= 59)
        or die "Unable to handle second '$sec'";
    my $fmt = "%04d%02d%02d%02d%02d%02d"; # YYYYMMDDHHMMSS
    return sprintf($fmt, $year, $month_num, $day, $hr, $min, $sec);
}
```

Which outputs the following:

```
Log Canonical Date : 20150527093333 [ May 27 09:33:33 ]
Log Canonical Date : 20150605093333 [ Jun 05 09:33:33 ]
Log Canonical Date : 20150610093333 [ Jun 10 09:33:33 ]
===> Date in range
Log Canonical Date : 20150620093333 [ Jun 20 09:33:33 ]
===> Date in range
Log Canonical Date : 20150630093333 [ Jun 30 09:33:33 ]
```

See also [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) (*Data elements and interchange formats*) for other properties of using a normalized / canonical timestamp.

Comment: Marvellous. This was the sort of thing I was thinking of - although I was thinking more in terms of `Time::Piece` so this is probably better yet as it's using the module requested.

Comment: Is there any way to do something like this without Time:Piece or Datetime::Format::Strptime?

Comment: Almost certainly. But why would you? Time::Piece has been a part of any standard Perl installation since Dec 2007.