# how to compare timestamp in array values iteratively

Tags: perl

I have an array

```
@array = ( 'Apr 11 21:14:25',
           'Apr 11 21:10:10',
           'Apr 11 21:09:10',
           'Apr 11 21:07:10',
         );
```

Here I want to comapare time stamps in a array 
Process:
 First value in a array should compare with second value to check time difference of 2 minutes or not?
 second value in  a array should compare with third value and again should check time difference of 2 minutes.
 Same process should go on

Any Ideas on How to acheive this in perl?

Comment: I can do in Java for this scenario.But I am new to perl.I am not having enough idea except basic idea.Did any other modules to be installed for this timestamps?

Comment: [Time::Piece](http://p3rl.org/Time::Piece) is a core module, no need to install it.

Comment: Check this module [Time::Piece](http://perldoc.perl.org/Time/Piece.html). It will help you to give an idea.

Comment: In Time::Piece module it includes Year and Day like Tue Apr 11 21:14:25 2006 format But i dont need day and year..Kindly helpful if you explained better than this

Comment: Yes, because without the Year, you can't tell what the difference is between two dates. 'Feb 28 23:59:00', 'Mar 01 00:02:00' - one or two days? Or more than a year?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Searching through a logfile with datetimes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31523080/searching-through-a-logfile-with-datetimes)

Comment: I just need to check for difference of 2 minutes.Please help me the above link is very complicated to me As I am new to Perl

Comment: You should grab a copy of Beginning Perl book by Ovid.

Comment: Time::Piece snippet to get you started: https://github.com/neilhwatson/nustuff/blob/master/perl/cheatsheet.pod#difference-or-two-date-stamps-in-days

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't really just hand out answers without you making an effort first. But it's lunchtime and I wanted a simple programming problem to work on.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

use Time::Piece;

my @times = (
  'Apr 11 21:14:25',
  'Apr 11 21:10:10',
  'Apr 11 21:09:10',
  'Apr 11 21:07:10',
);

# Need a year for this to make sense. Let's use
# the current one.
my $year = localtime->year;

# Convert the string dates to Time::Piece objects
my @timepieces = map {
  Time::Piece->strptime("$year $_", '%Y %b %d %H:%M:%S')
} @times;

for (1 .. $#times) {
  say "Comparing $times[$_ - 1] with $times[$_]";
  # Use abs() so we don't care which is larger.
  my $seconds = abs($timepieces[$_ - 1] - $timepieces[$_]);

  if ($seconds == 120) {
    say 'Exactly two minutes difference';
  } elsif ($seconds > 120) {
    say 'More than two minutes difference';
  } else {
    say 'Less than two minutes difference';
  }
}
```

Comment: This is assuming that all of them are in the same year. But a counter example is `my @times = ( 'Jan 01 00:00:01', 'Dec 31 23:58:01', 'Dec 31 23:56:01')` The difference is in this example is two minutes, but between two different years, I think assuming the dates are in the same year will not work with this example

Comment: That's true. But without a year included in the input data, you can't be sure that there are two different years in your example.

Comment: The sample provided is ordered desc,  if we have this assumption that the data are always ordered we may know that jumping from jan to dec is moving to  next year(s) ... of course the main problem will be: is it next year or the year which follows next year or the successive one ... etc. I think this problem cannot be solved if we don't have some extra assumptions by OP for instance: dates are always ordered desc, difference between dates is max 1 year no more (so we are sure we will be sure that it must be next year and no more.)

Comment: All true. I think we're just demonstrating the idiocy of having datestamps without years :-)